# Asus Maximus motherboard problems after <1 week

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, bsod

**CPU** | Intel Boxed Core I7-6700K 4.00 GHz 8M Processor Cache 4 LGA 1151 BX80662I76700K

**CPU Cooler** | Corsair Hydro Series H55 Quiet Edition Liquid CPU Cooler (CW-9060010-WW

**Motherboard** | [ASUS ROG MAXIMUS VIII HERO LGA1151 DDR4 M.2 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 Type A Type C Intel Z170 ATX Motherboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012NH1SK8)

**Memory** | Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (4 x 4GB) DDR4 DRAM 3000MHz (PC4-24000) C15 memory kit for DDR4 Systems (CMK16GX4M4B3000C15R)

Last week I built a new PC, and for a few days everything was running flawlessly. Perfect fitment, booted up on the first try, amazing performance - everything was running perfect.

Just last night I got CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT BSoD and I had to force shutdown. It was a little glitchy on the restart, but eventually I made it back to my desktop. The same error screen occurred shortly after and again I was forced to hard reset. This time it doesn't boot. No BIOS, no monitor signal, no nothing.
The motherboard itself is throwing 2 codes on the LED display, seemingly randomly:

- 55 - No memory installed
- 32 - CPU initialization error

Things I have already tried in attempt to troubleshoot:

- I've tried the CLR_CMOS button on mobo sporadically hoping for the best
- Took all the memory out and tried single-stick, single-slot startups to no avail
- Removed all USB devices on boot hoping the drivers were maybe interfering with Windows startup
- I tried booting this morning with similar results

I have a fresh, legit copy of Windows 10 Home Edition installed. The only part I took out of my old build was an 850W Corsair PSU which has not given me any problems in the past (also only ~1 year old).
I have PC building experience in the past, so I'm very frustrated at the situation. Any sort of help would be appreciated. I don't think I've ever been this lost troubleshooting before, and I don't even know where I would begin with contacting tech support.

Thank you for reading this far.

Comment: [A Guide to the CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT Blue Screen of Death Error](http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2013/01/clock-watchdog-timeout/) is one of many links returned by searching for "CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT bsod"

Comment: share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Mnidump**

Comment: @DavidPostill, He can't get it to boot, that's the problem, not repeated BSODs.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'd say this is quite a well asked question, with a lot of information laid out, seeking some validation and confirmation on what the community thinks. He's clearly tried all the diagnostics he could think of. Your link recommends things like system restore, updating drivers etc, where his system won't POST. I've seen a lot worse first posts around ;)

Comment: Send the mobo back under warranty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these symptoms seem CPU related:

- CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT - Typically related to a faulty CPU
- 55 - No memory installed - i7 processors have an integrated memory controller
- 32 - CPU initialization error - Speaks for itself.

Whether it's a case of a faulty motherboard or a faulty CPU is the difficult part to establish, but the CPU itself seems the most likely. It sounds like you've done all main forms of diagnostic required, and confirmed there are no overclocks or bad settings by clearing the CMOS. Perhaps attempt to reseat it and check the pins are all in order, although if you had it booting for a while before hand without too much issue, I'd suspect it's failed.

If you happen to have another Socket 1151 CPU around to test that would be ideal. I wouldn't be too surprised if an RMA is in order.

One other consideration is whether the CPU has adequate cooling. Whilst I think this CPU is faulty, it could be that heat caused the issue initially, and if there was a problem with the heatsink or it's surface with the CPU, it could be a problem after you get a replacement.

I don't suspect heat is the issue you're having at the moment as you state you've left the machine overnight and it still didn't work in the morning, however if you do get the CPU replaced, keep a close eye on the temperatures for a few days with a temperature monitoring software tool. If they do get too high, be sure to power down the machine and check the cooler is functioning correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have another 1151. Thanks for the quick response though - what you're saying is the same as what I'm thinking. I didn't want it to be true, but I don't know if I have another option.

Comment: @JohnZachariah Better that shows a fault immediately and in such a dramatic way you can diagnose it, than slowly degrading over the next year and making you go slightly insane and potentially being out of the return window though :)

Comment: Check the cooler carefully. It may be faulty: if there is air in the hose or the pump is not operating properly, it may not be cooling the CPU adequately. It may be OK at low power or idle, but may not be able to keep up under load. Don't open it though: it has antifreeze in it which is corrosive.

Comment: @Yorik Certainly worth checking, especially if the CPU does get replaced as heat may have been what started causing a problem in the first place. I don't suspect it'll resolve this issue as the machine didn't come on even after being left hours over night, but I'll add a part in my answer.

Comment: right, it may be a potential source of the failure, rather than a solution to the current problem.